# Maximum length of pencil in a pencil case

Tags: geometry, 3d, solid-geometry

What is the maximum length of an unsharpened, cylindrical pencil inside an empty rectangular pencil box?

Or, in a rectangular cuboid of dimensions $x \times y \times z$, what is the maximum possible height of a right cylinder of radius *r*, that can be inscribed within? Assume $x \ge y \ge z \ge 2r \ge 0$.

Comment: the assumption makes sure the pencil goes in corner to corner rather than from one face to the opposite face ie. along the length of the cuboid, right?

Comment: I imagine there are still some cases that requires the pencil to go from one face to opposite face, e.g. when $x >> y > z = 2r > 0$, if y is only slightly longer than the diameter, the pencil should fits better along $x$ direction than lying diagonally on the $x-y$ plane, because rotating the pencil slightly would take some length.

Comment: Though I should have eliminated the case where $x \ge y \ge 2r \ge z \ge 0$, where the box is so thin that the pencil has to stand on the $z$ direction.

Comment: Yes sorry, I had in my mind z>=2d. Do you think it would always go in corner to corner then?